# Cannot get Unicode Executable to Run Python Script

Tags: python, jupyter, cx-freeze

I have created a Tkinter Application Using JupyterLab.

I have converted this to py file.

I then used cxfreeze to confert this file to an executable.

However when running the resulting file, I am receiving the following error in terminal:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: invalid flags 1553723964 in 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010c46a5c0 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
logout
```

Is there a known way to convert the Ipynb file to a stand alone executable?

I am using MacOS. I'm unsure if this will affect how I should solve this problem.

Using cxfreeze I was able to create the exe file without issue.

Comment: Which Python version are you running?

Comment: I am running python version 3.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [cx_Freeze Github issue](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/399) addressing this error. According to the latest comment you should try applying [this patch](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/4c18633ba2331d980f00aff075f17135399c43c5) to your install of `freeze.py`.

Other comments also suggest that having stray environment variables may cause similar issues.

Let me know if that helped (if it doesn't, I'll need to have a closer look at your code!).